# Errors using R to write KNN from scratch

Tags: r, knn, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to create the knn formula from scratch in R.  This is the code I have so far...

```
train.df <- read.csv("SchoolkidsTrain.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ',')

test.df <- read.csv("SchoolkidsTest.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ',')

train <- train.df

test <- test.df

normalize <- function(x){

  return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))

}

distance <- function(a,b){

  d = 0

  for(i in c(1:length(a)-1)){

    d = d + (a[[i]]-b[[i]])^2

  }

  d = sqrt(d)

  return(d)
}

knn <- function(test_d, train_d, k){

  prediction <- c()

  for(i in c(1:nrow(test_d))){

    dist = c()

    char = c()

    yes = 0

    no = 0

    for(j in c(1:nrow(train_d))){

      dist <- c(dist, distance(test_d[i,], train_d[j,]))
    }


  }

}
```

Every time I run the program, I get the following output in RStudio:

> normalize <- function(x){
>   +   return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
>   + }
>   I'm unsure of what this means, but I have a feeling that there's something wrong with my code.  A sample of the dataset can be seen below.

Gender  Grade   Age Type    Grades  Sports  Looks   Money   Goal
boy 5   11  Rural   1   2   4   3   Sports
boy 5   10  Rural   2   1   4   3   Popular
girl    5   11  Rural   4   3   1   2   Popular

The knn is trying to predict what the goal is for each student in the test dataset.

Comment: This looks like you just typed the function name `normalize` then pressed `Run`.  Rather than something like: `train = normalize(train.df)`.

Comment: Normalize funtion will not work on factor variable . It will only work for numeric variable.